# R long to wide with pair of columns

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I am trying to convert a dataset from long to wide format.

My input data is below:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2011:2013),
             T1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
             T2 = c("b", "c", "d"),
             V1 = rep(1, 3),
             V2 = rep(2, 3))
```

where the desired output is

```
df2 <- data.frame(year = c(2011:2013),
              a = c(1, 0, 0),
              b = c(2, 1, 0),
              c = c(0, 2, 1),
              d = c(0, 0, 2))
```

I think what makes this more challenging (at least for me) is the fact that column T1 and V1 are "pairs" and the same is true for T2 and V2. Tried to gather column T1 and T2 then spread (or dcast) it, but doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I've tried.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- setDT(df)
tmp <- melt(dt, measure.vars = c("T1", "T2"))
dcast(tmp, year ~ value, value.var = c("V1", "V2"))
```

When I dcast it, V1_a and V2_a takes value 1 and 2, respectively, not allowing me to keep the "pair" structure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code that you've tried, even though it didn't work

Comment: I've updated my question! My apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` first to get data in long format with `T` and `V` pairs separately and then use `pivot_wider` to move it back to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -year, names_to = c(".value", "cols"), 
               names_pattern = "([A-Z])(\\d)") %>%
  select(-cols) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = T, values_from = V, values_fill = list(V = 0))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#   year     a     b     c     d
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2011     1     2     0     0
#2  2012     0     1     2     0
#3  2013     0     0     1     2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here, we can use `measure` with `patterns` in the `data.table` syntax

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^T", "^V")), 
      year ~ value1, value.var = 'value2', fill = 0)
#   year a b c d
#1: 2011 1 2 0 0
#2: 2012 0 1 2 0
#3: 2013 0 0 1 2
```